# Angularfire2 : Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am writing a application using angular fire2. I have set my databse rule to allow only. I don't want unauthenticated users to read data. I will like to know how to configure angularfire2 reference for firebase real-time databsae to access the data
here is my ref
`this.categoryRef = this.db.list('category')`;
thanks

Comment: Can you show how you have defined your firestore rules

Comment: here is my firebase realtime database rules  ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"